# Flatpickr - Changing dateFormat for angular 2

Tags: angular, flatpickr

I'm trying to understand his documentation but can't quite figure out how you change the date format from numbers to letters. I'm trying to get 1st April 2018 for example.

```
<input type="text" 
      mwlFlatpickr 
      [(ngModel)]="rangeValue"
      name="Datepicker"
      mode="range"
      dateFormat="Y-m-d">
```

I don't know if I need to do this on the html or in my component.ts file.

If I need to do it in my component.ts file I am looking for an example on how to do this. The [documentation](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angularx-flatpickr/docs/directives/FlatpickrDirective.html#dateFormat) on this isn't that helpful.

Really appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

Left out the documentation you need to wrap it in square brackets like so:
**[dateFormat]="'dd M Y'"**